# Search string for percentage

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I'm using c#. I need a method that will take a string as input, search for the percent symbol in that string, then return the number directly in front of the percent symbol. for example `"asdf sdfa asf 32% asdf"` would return 32. `"asdfl asfi asdf kd 34.5% adsfkjfg"` would return 34.5. I know how to find the index of the percent symbol then loop backwards searching for a space, and return everything in the middle. I feel there is probably a more efficient way to do it.

Comment: `I know how to find the index...` can you show us that attempt, and explain how it didn't work?

Comment: No, that's as efficient as it gets. If by efficient, you mean more readability, you might want to try simple Regex pattern that can capture such thing. The pattern would be "[\-\+]?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?". You might need to add comma there too, if necessary.

Comment: Is it inefficient to the point its causing any kind of problem whatsoever?

Comment: @Gavin, you can up-vote as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var result = str.Split(' ')
                .Where(s => s.Contains('%'))
                .Select(s => s.Trim('%'));
```

**Explanation**

[Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) turns your input string into an `IEnumerable<string>`, [Where](http://www.dotnetperls.com/where) selects only those strings that contain the searched character `%` and [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) projects each of those elements, such that the new elements do not contain the character `%`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) to achieve this using the following pattern:

```
(^|\s)\d+(.\d+)?(?=%)
```

And in the code:

```
var match = 
   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(input, @"(^|\s)\d+(.\d+)?(?=%)");

if (match.Success)
{
    string value = match.Value;
}
```

And here's the pattern broken down into pieces:

**`(^|\s`)**: Specifies that the rest of the pattern should look either at the beginning of the string or after a white-space. As a result, "Hello 3%" would be a match, but "Hello3%" won't be.

**`\d+`**: Matches one or more digits.

**`(.\d+)?`**: Specifies that **if** there is a "**.** ", there should be one or more decimal digits as well.

**`(?=%)`**: Is a lookahead group used to match a **"%"** and return everything captured before it (i.e. the value).

Comment: I would say: string value = match.Value.Trim(); to avoid leading spaces before the decimal number parsed.